# no permissions allowed auto android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to get weather information using gps location, but the problem is  getting value for my location 0,0 ("latitude , longitude"). When I go to setting for my phone -> " permission " found no permissions allowed, and I have to activate the permission manually. Then app start working fine .

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ionicframework.myapp574503">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.ionicframework.myapp574503;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    RequestQueue rq;
    TextView timeDesc, windspeedDesc;
    String wind;
    GPSTracker gps;
    LocationManager locationManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        windspeedDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // create class object
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            String url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxxxxxxxx/conditions/hourly/forecast10day/geolookup/q/"+latitude+","+longitude+".json";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            sendjsonrequest(url);

            // \n is for new line
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

    public void sendjsonrequest(String url) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    JSONObject stationsJO = response.getJSONObject("location");
                    JSONArray array = stationsJO.optJSONArray("days");

                    wind= stationsJO.getString("city");
                    windspeedDesc.setText(wind);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tested on version 4.4.2 and it worked fine and permission auto allowed but on version 7.0 I have to activate permission manually from setting 
any ideas ?

Comment: Can u give the runtime permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ? for Android Version 6.0 or above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for Runtime Permission in Android Version 6.0 or above

```
private int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 100;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
              if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainFragmentActivity.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainFragmentActivity.this,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                     } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainFragmentActivity.this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                     }
              } 
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but i have red on ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: its same , red line  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: so i think u have an issue in your android studio because this all code are confidential code i will put it after doing self check.

Comment: will try to invailed and restart android studio

Comment: just remove Manifest.permission before ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and try does it can ask you or suggest you to import it by pressing ALT+ENTER ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the runtime permission.

You do that using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`

There is a tutorial on doing this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)